# Asp.Net Core Rest API (VS 2015 version) with Team Build?

Tags: asp.net-core, tfsbuild

I recently submitted an Asp.Net Core (VS2015 style) project to our build team for automated builds. They came back and said its not pulling down the nuget packages. They did install VS2015 Update 3, Visual Studio Tooling, .Net Core runtime. Is there something else I need to do for the project to work in Team Build?

Comment: Are your packages hosted on NuGet, or are you using a local feed? Perhaps following page can help. You need to add another TFS Build step, in order to restore NuGet packages: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/build/team-build-nuget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure [the .NET Core tools](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015) has been installed on your build agent.
For on-premise TFS, add a "**Command line**" step before build step. In the Command line step, invoke [dotnet restore command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/tools/dotnet-restore) to restore the assemblies in your project. The $(Build.SourcesDirectory) presents the path:"c:\agent_work\1\s".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will send this over to them and see if it works.

Comment: Seems like we're still getting the error. They changed the **\*.sln to point to the actual solution file, but we don't have a nuget.config in asp.net core, correct?

Comment: @SledgeHammer I'm sorry that I have made a mistake, I have edited my reply, please have a check.